# Syntax highlighting gone in Android Studio 3.3.1

Tags: android-studio, syntax-highlighting

### Recently, syntax highlighting stopped working for me in Android Studio.

And I believe it's related to my project and not Android Studio itself.

---

From my understanding, the below error message gets thrown when I open certain files and the syntax highlighting isn't executed. If I edit the file by removing a line of code or so, however, syntax highlighting will show up again.

Going through and searching for the stacktrace doesn't give me any real indicator on what might be wrong, so here I am. Do you know what might be wrong?

I've tried clearing caches, reinstalling and playing with different settings in Android Studio without any effect, which leads me to believe that this is related to the project directly. Moreover, if I create a new project, syntax highlighting works as normal.

**What I see...**

### [image: Without syntax]

**Full stacktrace...**

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.caches.lightClasses.LazyLightClassMemberMatchingError$NoMatch: Couldn't match ClsMethodImpl:hashCode MemberIndex(index=10) (with 0 parameters)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.caches.lightClasses.LazyLightClassDataHolder.assertMatches(LazyLightClassDataHolder.kt:145)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.caches.lightClasses.LazyLightClassDataHolder.access$assertMatches(LazyLightClassDataHolder.kt:32)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.caches.lightClasses.LazyLightClassDataHolder$LazyLightClassData$getOwnMethods$$inlined$map$lambda$1.invoke(LazyLightClassDataHolder.kt:138)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.caches.lightClasses.LazyLightClassDataHolder$LazyLightClassData$getOwnMethods$$inlined$map$lambda$1.invoke(LazyLightClassDataHolder.kt:100)
        at kotlin.SafePublicationLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:107)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.asJava.elements.KtLightMemberImpl.getClsDelegate(KtLightMemberImpl.kt)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.asJava.elements.KtLightMemberImpl$_modifierList$2.invoke(KtLightMemberImpl.kt:47)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.asJava.elements.KtLightMemberImpl$_modifierList$2.invoke(KtLightMemberImpl.kt:35)
        at kotlin.SafePublicationLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:107)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.asJava.elements.KtLightMemberImpl.get_modifierList(KtLightMemberImpl.kt)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.asJava.elements.KtLightMemberImpl.getModifierList(KtLightMemberImpl.kt:52)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.asJava.elements.KtLightMethodImpl.getModifierList(KtLightMethodImpl.kt:127)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.AnnotationUtil.isAnnotated(AnnotationUtil.java:244)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.AnnotationUtil.lambda$isAnnotated$4(AnnotationUtil.java:234)
        at java.util.stream.MatchOps$1MatchSink.accept(MatchOps.java:90)
        at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
        at java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(MatchOps.java:230)
        at java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(MatchOps.java:196)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.anyMatch(ReferencePipeline.java:449)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.AnnotationUtil.isAnnotated(AnnotationUtil.java:234)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.MetaAnnotationUtil.isMetaAnnotated(MetaAnnotationUtil.java:154)
        at com.intellij.execution.junit.JUnitUtil.lambda$isJUnit5TestClass$1(JUnitUtil.java:280)
        at com.intellij.psi.util.CachedValuesManager.lambda$getCachedValue$0(CachedValuesManager.java:140)
        at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValueImpl.doCompute(PsiCachedValueImpl.java:49)
        at com.intellij.util.CachedValueBase.getValueWithLock(CachedValueBase.java:222)
        at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValue.getValueWithLock(PsiCachedValue.java:60)
        at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValueImpl.getValue(PsiCachedValueImpl.java:38)
        at com.intellij.util.CachedValuesManagerImpl.getCachedValue(CachedValuesManagerImpl.java:87)
        at com.intellij.psi.util.CachedValuesManager.getCachedValue(CachedValuesManager.java:139)
        at com.intellij.psi.util.CachedValuesManager.getCachedValue(CachedValuesManager.java:126)
        at com.intellij.execution.junit.JUnitUtil.isJUnit5TestClass(JUnitUtil.java:276)
        at com.intellij.execution.junit.JUnit5Framework.isTestClass(JUnit5Framework.java:52)
        at com.intellij.testIntegration.JavaTestFramework.isTestClass(JavaTestFramework.java:64)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.TestFrameworks.computeFramework(TestFrameworks.java:92)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.TestFrameworks.lambda$detectFramework$0(TestFrameworks.java:63)
        at com.intellij.psi.util.CachedValuesManager.lambda$getCachedValue$0(CachedValuesManager.java:140)
        at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValueImpl.doCompute(PsiCachedValueImpl.java:49)
        at com.intellij.util.CachedValueBase.getValueWithLock(CachedValueBase.java:222)
        at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValue.getValueWithLock(PsiCachedValue.java:60)
        at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValueImpl.getValue(PsiCachedValueImpl.java:38)
        at com.intellij.util.CachedValuesManagerImpl.getCachedValue(CachedValuesManagerImpl.java:87)
        at com.intellij.psi.util.CachedValuesManager.getCachedValue(CachedValuesManager.java:139)
        at com.intellij.psi.util.CachedValuesManager.getCachedValue(CachedValuesManager.java:126)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.TestFrameworks.detectFramework(TestFrameworks.java:62)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.core.platform.impl.JvmIdePlatformKindTooling.getTestIcon(JvmIdePlatformKindTooling.kt:60)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.highlighter.KotlinTestRunLineMarkerContributor.getInfo(KotlinTestRunLineMarkerContributor.kt:66)
        at com.intellij.execution.lineMarker.RunLineMarkerProvider.getLineMarkerInfo(RunLineMarkerProvider.java:46)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LineMarkersPass.queryProviders(LineMarkersPass.java:174)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LineMarkersPass.lambda$doCollectInformation$3(LineMarkersPass.java:96)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.Divider.divideInsideAndOutsideInOneRoot(Divider.java:80)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LineMarkersPass.doCollectInformation(LineMarkersPass.java:91)
        at com.intellij.codeHighlighting.TextEditorHighlightingPass.collectInformation(TextEditorHighlightingPass.java:69)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$null$1(PassExecutorService.java:423)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1164)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$doRun$2(PassExecutorService.java:416)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:580)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:525)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.doRun(PassExecutorService.java:415)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$run$0(PassExecutorService.java:391)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ReadMostlyRWLock.executeByImpatientReader(ReadMostlyRWLock.java:147)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.executeByImpatientReader(ApplicationImpl.java:222)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.run(PassExecutorService.java:389)
        at com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncherImpl$VoidForkJoinTask$1.exec(JobLauncherImpl.java:161)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

Comment: Try invalidate cache and restart.

Comment: @user1209216 read the 5th paragraph. OP already tried that

Comment: Try inspecting code Analyse > Inspect Code > Whole Project. The errors will be thrown if any then again try invalidate cache and sync the gradle files again.

Answer (score 1):

**Naturally when posting about an issue, the solution reveals itself shortly thereafter.**

I have equals & hashcode overridden in one class (Entity) and both methods are marked as final. The issue comes up whenever a data-class extends Entity, Im guessing because its trying to create its own equals & hashcode methods, but cant.

Hope this helps anyone else out there! I think the behavior is correct (a data class has a very specific equals/hashcode) so I dont consider this a bug in the Kotlin plugin, but a better error message would be preferrable in the future.